# postgres 9.4 timezone unknown

Tags: postgresql, timezone

My company just upgraded from postgres 9.0.4 to postgres 9.4.2

when timezone unknown was specified in the postgres.conf file in 9.0.4, postgres "figured out" what the local timezone was, and set that as the local timezone.

in 9.4.2 the documentation says that if not specified it uses GMT.
I want to know if there's a way to get the legacy behavior

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer mostly from information from Tom Lane.

postgres 9.2+ "figures out" the local timezone during initdb.